Want 1366 x 768 resolution with secondary monitor
Ubuntu Noble Numbat. I find that what works for Lubuntu does not work with Ubuntu. The secondary monitor is an older Toshiba TV with a VGA input. It also has an HDMI which I haven't tried yet but I want to use VGA anyhow. I searched the web for solutions but they seem to apply to older versions of Ubuntu. One answer for Wayland, I guess, doesn't allow you to customize to a higher res than what is already showing. My highest res in Display menu is 1024 768, which is no good for the Toshiba TV.
Any suggestions welcome. I don't mind inputting code for every bootup. I just want 1366 x 768.
